# I keep getting:Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019, hook

I've tried everything creating a separate function for a hook using npm link inside the react and the react-dom and even tried implementing hooks at different levels anyway here is the problem trying to use fuse I'm using visual studio enterprise

```js
static renderForecastsTable(forecasts) {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState(''); // <-- problem line
  const fuse = new Fuse(forecasts, { keys: ['mjesto'] })
  const results = fuse.search(query);
  console.log(results);
  return (...)

  function handleOnSearch({ currentTarget = {} }) {
    const { value } = currentTarget;
    setQuery = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read this.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html
This is one of the rules of react hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks can only be called from functional components. You could refactor your code into a functional component like...

```
function ForecastsTable() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const handleOnSearch = () => {
    ...
  };

  return (
  );
}
```

Comment: yep that's it i was using it as  a class component